# How to make Git commit history show up at Redmine issue tracker

Tags: git, hook, redmine

I followed the instruction of this article and setup an Redmine site on my DreamHost account with Git repository.

It works fine so far, I could manage my project using Redmine, and commit my code to the Git repository using SSH, and I could browse my source code and commit history using Redmine user interface.

But there is my problem: It does not hook Git commit history with issue tracker like the official Redmine site.

For example, there is a commit log listed on http://www.redmine.org/issues/7000.

But in my case, I created a ticket which is numbered by Redmine as #5, and I created a commit log like the following:

```
commit 580fdb33877d7b4167863f5138973b7a83b352aa
Author: Brian Hsu <XXXX.XXXX@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 11 11:43:43 2011 +0800

    Add README file. (#5)

commit 9cf0d98a319ffca501dc541c76a6cff9a32d6146
Author: Brian Hsu <XXXX.XXXX@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 11 11:40:00 2011 +0800

    Inital commit.
```

I could see these commit in the source code browser in version control tab and click "#5" to go to the issue #5. But in that ticket, it does not show the commit log of 580fdb33877d7b4167863f5138973b7a83b352aa in that ticket.

So how could I hook Git and Redmine issue tracker?

BTW, I followed the master/develop two branch workflow mentioned by "[A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)", so I would like Redmine to hook the commit in develop branch instead of master.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, my fault.

There are keywords to associate the commit history with issue tracker tickets listed on the  page http://yourredminesite/settings/edit?tab=repositories

Change my commit log with "refs #5" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Redmine but AFAIK you should be able to just use '#', e.g. #5 as the reference. Then the commits mentioning the reference ID should show up in the issue.

See [Redmine - Defect #7593](https://www.redmine.org/issues/7593) that seems to cover this issue, although the ticket is closed.

In summary they recommend using '*' in your list of keywords (logon as Redmine Admin user - then navigate to Administration/Settings/Repositories/Referencing keywords). The OP the comments that he had to delete and re-add the git repository to the Redmine project to trigger reparsing of the commit comments so the issues were updated with the correct links.